# if and else statement in php

Tags: php, mysql

Can anyone please help me figure this out. I am trying to make it so that an image is displayed when the value in mysql table = 1. i've got that bit covered and the image is displayed. Is there a way to include an if or else statement to say if the value in the mysql table is 0 then display different image?

Thanks.

```
<?php
        $get_social_set = get_social();

        while ($social = mysql_fetch_array($get_social_set)) 

        {


    ?>


<table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="10">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="30"><?php echo"
            <img width=30px heigh=24px src=\"assets/img/icons/tick.png\"/>"; } ?></td>
```

Comment: That's really php basics, you maybe should learn a little php before asking questions about it.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($social['name_of_field_youre_checking'] == 0) { ... }
```

Comment: thank you so much have been trying to figure it out for ages.

Comment: what do i put in the brackets { ... } is that where the image directory goes? because how i'm typing it it won't work.

Comment: that's up to you. I don't know what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work in a php file:

```
<?php

$image = false;
// get results from database
// process results
if ( $results === 1) {
    $image = 'tick.png';
} else {
    $image = 'something.png';
}
?>
<img src="<?php echo $image ?>" />
```

Bye

Comment: thanks this code seems to work but now where the image is just set to 'tick.png' it can not find the image directory. but when i try pointing it to the full directory this doesnt work and i get a syntax error. :/

Answer (score 0):

Name image files as foreg : tick0.png , tick1.png and use the code below 'SHOW' being your db fieldname :

```
 <?php echo"<img width=30px heigh=24px src=\"assets/img/icons/tick".$social['SHOW'].".png\"/>"; } ?>
```